# Which color combination to use on websites?

Tags: web, colors

Just interested in knowing if there are any good (and short! :-) ) articles which talk about the color combinations that would look good on a website.

i.e For tables (odd and even row), which one will be good in all situations
For alerts? For menus? etc

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to colors, I don't think there are any set colors like you ask. There are no articles that say "ALL MENUS MUST BE BLUE!".

For alerts, either a light or golden yellow is used (so that you don't burn your eyes out), or a dark maroon or peachy pink for more prominent alerts. Menus can be any color, but they should match your color scheme.

I think what you are implicitly asking for are color schemes. Take a look at these resources:

- Prefab [color pallets](http://www.colorcombos.com/) for inspiration
- [Color scheme](http://colorschemedesigner.com/) helper chooser
- [Aviary (Toucan) color chooser](http://aviary.com/online/color-swatches?lang=en) (flash)
- [Visibone color lab](http://www.visibone.com/colorlab/)

Related articles

- [How color schemes work](http://www.worqx.com/color/combinations.htm)
- [How to choose a color scheme](http://veerle-v2.duoh.com/blog/comments/choosing_color_combinations/)
- [How to select color combinations](http://www.masternewmedia.org/how_to_select_perfectly_matching_color_combinations/)

In addition, if you are serious about your website, I strongly STRONGLY suggest reading this book:

*Steve Krugs Dont Make Me Think*

The book is in an easy to read (and skim) format, and is about colors, interfaces, buttons, and designing the easy-to-use website with lots of pictures and examples. For me, it was a quick read ( < 1 hr), and it changed my life.

Answer (score 0):

simple advise : do not use many colors. select three or max four different color. and work with their shades.

for color scheme selections nothing beats...

http://kuler.adobe.com/